# C sprint change Left-justify width

Tags: c, padding

I need to use sprintf() to do padding space character in string, however, I hope that the length of the padding can be changed with the length of the string.

The sample code function pcMsgPadding, I want to change left-justify width in sprintf, width depends on iLen.

It’s now a fixed width of 20.

What should i do or is there any other way?

Sample Code:

```
#define LCD_COLUMNS 20
char *pcMsgPadding(int iLen, const char* pcMsg)
{
  char *pcBuf = (char*) malloc(LCD_COLUMNS*sizeof(char));
  sprintf(pcBuf, "%-20s", pcMsg);
  return pcBuf;
}

void vDisplay(const char* pcMsg)
{
  printf(pcMsg);
}
void main()
{
  vDisplay(pcMsgPadding(15, "Test Message"));
}
```

Comment: See [sprintf - Parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters) >(optional) integer value or * that specifies minimum field width.

Comment: You're not allocating enough memory

Comment: Olaf Dietsche Thank you offer comments and help.

Comment: You should store the result of `pcMsgPadding`. Otherwise you cannot free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `sprintf(pcBuf, "%*s", iLen, pcMsg);`.

The whole program with some problems fixed (added includes, removed the `malloc` cast, you should not use a variable as first parameter in `printf`, `main` must return `int`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LCD_COLUMNS 20
char *pcMsgPadding(int iLen, const char* pcMsg)
{
  char *pcBuf = malloc(LCD_COLUMNS*sizeof(char));
  sprintf(pcBuf, "%*s", iLen, pcMsg);
  return pcBuf;
}

void vDisplay(const char* pcMsg)
{
  printf("%s", pcMsg);
}

int main(void) {
    vDisplay(pcMsgPadding(15, "Test Message"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This still has the same problem as OP, allocates too little memory.

Comment: It allocates 20 bytes and the string will have 15 + 1 bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: But LCD_COLUMNS  * sizeof(char) != 20 ?

Comment: Think about `pcMsgPadding(100, "Test Message")`, now you have `LCD_COLUMNS < iLen`.